# Saving project with a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt, plc

I use batch files between my PLC and computer. PLC sending some commands to PC via batch files. For example I open a program or close. It works well done. But when I close the program It does not save anything.

I use command below:

```
taskkill /F /IM myprogram.exe
```

How can I close the program with saving?

Answer (score 0):

That command kills the process, not allowing it to perform any actions when it closes. It just shuts down and exits.

You could try to omit the `/F` option, and save all data when your program gets the command to exit.